# How many tags can have same id in document

Tags: xhtml, css-selectors

I know there can be only one unique ID attribute per document. 
To be sure, I need real doc link where this is written.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/global.html#adef-id:

> This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat a unique ID exactly seven times before the W3 will knock on your door. It's kind of like the bloody mary thing in the bathroom mirror except way geekier.

Comment: id="foo" id="foo" id="foo" id="foo" id="foo" id="foo" id="foo"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `id` attribute as many times in an XHTML document as you like, but you shouldn't be using the same `id` multiple times - that's what classes are for.